# Select rows using group by and in each group get column values based on highest of another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get latest field based on another field in group by
we have

Table "SchoolReview"

| Id | SchoolId | Review | Point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | rv1 | 8 |
| 2 | 1 | rv2 | 7 |
| 3 | 2 | rv3 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | rv4 | 7 |
| 5 | 3 | rv5 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | rv6 | 8 |

I need to group by SchoolId and the inside group I need to get Review and Point from highest "Id" column.

I dont need "Id" coulmn but even if I get it for this solution its okay.

Result I am looking for shall look like this.

| SchoolId | Review | Point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rv2 | 7 |
| 2 | rv4 | 7 |
| 3 | rv6 | 8 |

Any one experienced in MS SQL Server can help in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sample data from other answer

```
SELECT *
INTO #Data
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 1, 'rv1', 8),
   (2, 1, 'rv2', 7),
   (3, 2, 'rv3', 4),
   (4, 2, 'rv4', 7),
   (5, 3, 'rv5', 2),
   (6, 3, 'rv6', 8)
) v (Id, SchoolId, Review, Point)

SELECT S.SchoolId,
       S.Review,
       S.Point 
FROM   #Data S
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Id = MAX(S1.Id),
           S1.SchoolId
    FROM   #Data S1
    GROUP BY SchoolId
) X ON X.Id = S.Id AND X.schoolId = S.SchoolId
ORDER BY X.SchoolId    
;
```

output

[image]

Comment: If you check this It do not gives the desired result `SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 1, 'rv1', 8),
   (2, 1, 'rv2', 7),
   (3, 2, 'rv3', 4),
   (4, 2, 'rv4', 7),
   (5, 3, 'rv5', 2),
   (6, 3, 'rv6', 8)
) v (Id, SchoolId, Review, Point)

Go
SELECT S.SchoolId, S.Review, S.Point
FROM   Data S
LEFT JOIN(
      SELECT Id = MAX(S1.Id), S1.SchoolId
      FROM   Data S1
      GROUP BY SchoolId
) X ON X.Id = S.Id


`

Comment: Sounds inefficient, what's wrong with window functions?

Comment: @Charlieface it's an alternative approach

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to group the rows, you simply need to select the appropriate rows from the table. In this case, using `ROW_NUMBER()` is an option:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 1, 'rv1', 8),
   (2, 1, 'rv2', 7),
   (3, 2, 'rv3', 4),
   (4, 2, 'rv4', 7),
   (5, 3, 'rv5', 2),
   (6, 3, 'rv6', 8)
) v (Id, SchoolId, Review, Point)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT SchoolId, Review, Point
FROM (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolId ORDER BY Id DESC) AS Rn
   FROM Data
) t
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Result:

```
SchoolId Review Point
---------------------
1        rv2    7
2        rv4    7
3        rv6    8
```

Comment: Thanks. your suggested script works like a charm